# How to get a particular event in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand how can I get a particular event in a function.
Below is my HTML code:

```
<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple" width="50">
</select>
Remove Item<input type="button" id="removeItem" value="click" disabled="disabled"/>
```

My jQuery function looks like:

```
$('#removeItem').click(function() {
    // $('option:selected', this).remove();
    console.log(this);
    $(this).find('option:selected').remove();
});
```

Above, when I do a `console.log(this)`, it actually prints element for "removeItem":

```
<input type="button" id="removeItem" value="click">
```

However, within the function, I want a reference to "mySelect" (my selectBox), so that I can execute  something like:

```
$('option:selected', this).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a data-element or use the direct #id element.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="removeItem" value="click" data-target='#mySelect' />
```

JS:

```
$('#removeItem').click(function(){
    $('option:selected', $($(this).data('target'))).remove();
});
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eqwqe2g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#removeItem").click(function(){
 $("#mySelect option:selected").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



<select id="mySelect" multiple="multiple" width="50">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
Remove Item<input type="button" id="removeItem" value="click"/>
```

Comment: thanks Gregory. This works, just want to know if there is a way i can access "#mySelect" element with "this" keyword. Currently "this" refers to the button item. Basically, i want to understand if there is a way to pass the context  for "#mySelect" element. Hope you are getting me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use element ID directly in JavaScript

```
console.log(mySelect);
$('option:selected', mySelect).remove();
```

But it is better to use

```
$("#mySelect option:selected")
```

For a better understanding `this` in event scope [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)